# Command php artisan serve on other network?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know that when i run this command:

```
php artisan serve --host=localhost
```

It works when other computer is on same network, but if someone from other network wanna access it is it possible? Im asking that because i can not check at the moment.

Comment: If your machine has a dedicated external IP then you should be able to access it, but if you are behind a router you will need to forward the 8000 port to that machine.

Comment: so if i dont have access to router it will not works

Comment: If there's a router and you don't have access to it then it's a problem... there are other ways to share it, you can google "share local site" for some answers... or if you are using Valet, which I recommend, then you can share : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/valet#sharing-sites ... Homestead (Vagrant) also has a share command.

Comment: ok i will try with valet then... tnx :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apart from setting correct rules for firewall and router you need to run the command with a reacheble host, i.e:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

or better to be explicit with your IP address

```
php artisan serve --host YOUR_IP_HERE
```

Comment: The first option with --host 0.0.0.0 works when you are running php artisan serve inside a docker container and trying to access it through the host.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18 in Virtualbox I just needed

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

for the additional firewall rule and then

```
php artisan serve --host=_your_ip_address
```

Now it works on every device in the network.

Thanks to this [Laracast Discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/how-to-access-localhost8000-in-a-remote-server-when-using-php-artisan-serve-digitalocean).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `php artisan serve may fail` you can just use the built in php server like this

  `php -S <ip-to-remote-serve>:<port> -t public public/index.php`

for example

```
php -S 192.168.100:8000 -t public public/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, You can try step in below.

Step 1. Go to Firewall & Network Protection

[Firewall & Network Protection Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpKBA.png)

Step 2. Search CLI like this And be sure checked the both private and public

[Allow an app through the firewall Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgsMw.png)

Last Step.

```
php artisan serve --host YOUR_IP_HERE --port YOUR_PORT_HERE
```

if the port still can't access. you can open port in firewall inbound. you can look at the link below
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/how-to-open-ports/